# Using coinmarketcap api v2 with google sheets - adding to js object with multiple calls

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I am using coinmarketcap api to populate google sheets with data. https://coinmarketcap.com/api/

They are making some changes that will make this difficult. The two changes that are messing me up are pagination and a change in the JSON structure.

Previously I would have a column of coin ids in google sheets. I would grab all the coin data from coinmarketcap then iterate through the javascript array to get data I needed. Here is an example

```
function getMarketCap(sheetname) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetname);

  var assets = [];

  var idRange = sheet.getRange("B1:B");
  var lastRow = getLastRowOfRange(idRange);

  var cellRange = sheet.getRange(1, 2, lastRow).getValues();
  var mcRange = sheet.getRange(1, 3, lastRow);

  var mcValues = [];

   for (var i = 0; i < cellRange.length; i++) {
    assets[i] = cellRange[i];
  }

  var CMCdata = JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/?limit=0')); 
  for (var i = 0; i < assets.length; i++) {

    mcValues[i] = [];
    for (var x = 0; x < CMCdata.length; x++) {
      if (assets[i] == CMCdata[x]["id"]) {
        mcValues[i][0] = CMCdata[x]["market_cap_usd"];
      }
      if (!mcValues[i][0]) {
        mcValues[i][0] = 'xxx';
      }      
    }
  }

  mcRange.setValues(mcValues); 
}
```

Now with v2 they are making it so you can only get 100 results at a time instead of all at once https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/ vs https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/?limit=0.

How can I do what I was doing before with these changes? Is it possible to make 12 requests (100 coins at a time for about 1200 total), appending the results each time and then iterate through the data? How would I do this? I only have a very basic knowledge of coding and someone helped me with the code shown above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this modification?

#### Modification points :

- From v1 to v2, there are the following modifications in your script.

  - `id` became `website_slug`.
  - `market_cap_usd` became `USD.market_cap`.
  - ID number became the key of each element.
- In order to request 12 API calls, the fetchAll method is used.

#### Modified script :

```
function getMarketCap(sheetname) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetname);
  var assets = [];
  var idRange = sheet.getRange("B1:B");
  var lastRow = getLastRowOfRange(idRange);
  var cellRange = sheet.getRange(1, 2, lastRow).getValues();
  var mcRange = sheet.getRange(1, 3, lastRow);
  var mcValues = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < cellRange.length; i++) {
    assets[i] = cellRange[i];
  }

  // Added script --- begin
  var req = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    req.push({
      muteHttpExceptions: true,
      method: "get",
      url: "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/?start=" + (i * 100 + 1),
    });
  }
  var responses = UrlFetchApp.fetchAll(req);
  var res = responses.filter(function(e){return e.getResponseCode() == 200}).map(function(e){return JSON.parse(e.getContentText())});
  if (responses.length != res.length) Logger.log("%s errors occurred.", responses.length - res.length);
  var mcValues = [];
  assets.forEach(function(e, h) {
    mcValues[h] = [];
    res.some(function(f) {
      Object.keys(f.data).some(function(g) {
        if (f.data[g].website_slug == e[0]) {
          mcValues[h][0] = f.data[g].quotes.USD.market_cap;
          return true;
        }        
      });
      if (mcValues[h][0]) return true;
    });
    if (!mcValues[h][0]) mcValues[h][0] = 'xxx';
  });
  // Added script --- end

  mcRange.setValues(mcValues); 
}
```

#### Note :

- When I tested this script, I noticed that the error due to the rate limitation sometimes occurs.

  - In this case, HTML including `<title>Access denied | api.coinmarketcap.com used Cloudflare to restrict access</title>` is returned.
  - In this script, when the error occurs, "errors occurred." is output using `Logger.log()`.
  - When the limitation error occurs, please wait until the restriction is released. I thought that if there are the access token and tokens for each user, users might be able to adjust the API calls. But I couldn't find such tokens. I'm sorry.

#### Reference :

- [fetchAll](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchAll(Object))

In my environment, I could confirm this modified script worked. But if this was not what you want, I'm sorry.

Comment: Wow this is amazing. Thanks so much! However I am running into one problem that can be recreated by adding a `website_slug` to the sheet that doesn't exist. Instead of the script printing 'xxx' I get an incorrect range error. I can fix this error by moving the line `if (!mcValues[h][0]) mcValues[h][0] = 'xxx';` inside the `Object.keys.some` method but then the `xxx` doesn't get printed the cell is just blank. Any ideas?

Comment: @user4584963 I'm sorry for the inconvenience. Can you provide a sample spreadsheet, because I cannot understand your situation? By this, I would like to modify my answer.

Comment: Yes here is a link https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UdPzg-On9RPnIROLVryoVNuS6dI3D6APnlwxUwdDXp8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Hmm it was working fine for me yesterday but can't seem to get it to work today.

Comment: @user4584963 I'm sorry for the inconvenience. In the case that ``xxx`` is put to most cells of a column, the reason is the rate limitation. It is considered that your situation might be due to the rate limitation. In this case, please wait until the restriction is released. I think that not being able to avoid this rate limitation is my responsibility, because I couldn't find the token like access token. I'm really sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: @user4584963 I confirmed that when the restriction was released, the script worked. But I'm sorry for the rate limitation.

Comment: Thank you for looking into this. I don't quite understand this rate limitation. Is this a limitation from coinmarketcap? I see that they say no more than 30 requests per limit. Is this what you are talking about?

Comment: @user4584963 I think that this is the rate limitation due to the access from one IP address. I think that there might be a lot of requests from Google (Google Apps Script) by many users. For example, when the rate limitation is occurring at Google, when I access from my local PC, I can retrieve data without the rate limitation. I think that if the token like access token can be used, because the rate limitation is for only you, you can always access and retrieve the data. But I couldn't find it. I'm sorry.

Comment: Oh I forgot to ask you, can you take a look at the spreadsheet again. I added a website_slug that doesn't exist and it is not filling in the cell with `xxx`. Can you see why not?

Comment: @user4584963 When ``website_slug`` which is not included in the data is put to the cell, you want to put ``xxx``. If my understanding is correct, this script works like that. If I misunderstand your question, please tell me.

Comment: Yes that is my intention, but I am instead getting this error when I run the script `Incorrect range width, was 0 but should be 1` and points to the line `mcRange.setValues(mcValues)`

Comment: @user4584963 I'm really sorry for the inconvenience. Unfortunately, in my environment, my modified script works and it cannot reproduce your situation. So I cannot debug your situation. When such error occurs, can you provide the sample spreadsheet, the response data retrieved from API and your current script? By this, it can debug. I think that this is the difference situation from your initial question. So if you can provide the information, could you please post it as a new question? By this, a lot of users including me can think of your solution. I'm sorry for my poor skill.

Comment: Take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50751358/google-sheets-incorrect-range-width-when-no-cmc-matches