# Google sheets incorrect range width when no cmc matches

Tags: javascript, google-sheets-api

I am using this function to pull information from coinmarketcap using their v2 api. The problem I am getting is that if a "website_slug" does not exist on coinmarketcap, I get an `incorrect range width` error instead of the function just putting `xxx` in the cell. This can be recreated by having a cell in column B that doesn't match a website_slug on cmc (https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/).

```
function getMarketCap(sheetname) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetname);  
  var assets = [];  
  var idRange = sheet.getRange("B1:B");
  var lastRow = getLastRowOfRange(idRange);  
  var cellRange = sheet.getRange(1, 2, lastRow).getValues();
  var mcRange = sheet.getRange(1, 3, lastRow);  
  var mcValues = [];  
  for (var i = 0; i < cellRange.length; i++) {
    assets[i] = cellRange[i];
  }  


  var req = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    req.push({
      muteHttpExceptions: true,
      method: "get",
      url: "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/?start=" + (i * 100 + 1),
    });
  }
  var responses = UrlFetchApp.fetchAll(req);
  var res = responses.filter(function(e){return e.getResponseCode() == 200}).map(function(e){return JSON.parse(e.getContentText())});
  if (responses.length != res.length) Logger.log("%s errors occurred.", responses.length - res.length);
  var mcValues = [];
  assets.forEach(function(e, h) {
    mcValues[h] = []
    res.some(function(f) {
      Object.keys(f.data).some(function(g) {
        if (f.data[g].website_slug == e[0]) {
          mcValues[h][0] = f.data[g].quotes.USD.market_cap;
          return true;
        }
      });
      if (mcValues[h][0]) return true;
    });
    if (!mcValues[h][0]) mcValues[h][0] = 'xxx';

  });

  mcRange.setValues(mcValues); 
}
```

Comment: Could you please modify ``if (!mcValues[h][0]) mcValues[h][0] == 'xxx';`` to ``if (!mcValues[h][0]) mcValues[h][0] = 'xxx';`` and try again?

Comment: @Tanaike If I make this change, all cells get filled with `xxx`

Comment: In my environment, it seems that it difference from your situation. When no website_slug is given, ``xxx`` is put to the cell. Other cells have the correct values. I thought that I might misunderstand about your question. If I misunderstand it, could you please tell me? I would like to solve your issue.

Comment: @Tanaike here is a link to the sheet. I have updated the above code to include the change you recommended. Now even if all website_slugs are correct I get `xxx` no matter what.

Comment: Thank you for replying. But unfortunately, I couldn't find the sheet.

Comment: sorry here is the link https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UdPzg-On9RPnIROLVryoVNuS6dI3D6APnlwxUwdDXp8/edit#gid=0

Comment: I tried the script using the values of your spreadsheet. In my environment, when the values of ``website_slugs`` are correct, the correct values are put in the cells. If the values of ``website_slugs`` are not included in the retrieved data, ``xxx`` is put. In my environment, it cannot reproduce your situation. So can I ask you about the situation when your issue occurs? For example, those are the condition of API server and the retrieved data from the server. I'm really sorry for my poor skill.

Comment: I tried it again and it worked. Im not sure why it wasn't working before. Maybe I was being rate limited. Is there an easy way I can check if I'm being rate limited?

Comment: I'm really sorry for the inconvenience. I have already prepared it. Please confirm this line ``if (responses.length != res.length) Logger.log("%s errors occurred.", responses.length - res.length);``

Comment: Im not familiar with using the logger. Where do I look for the errors to appear? In the console?

Comment: I'm sorry. I couldn't understand about the console. Can I ask you about the console you say? And/or do you want to output the log as a file?

Comment: I just don't know how I can tell if I am being rate limited by coinmarketcap. Where should I look to see the error message?

Comment: You can see how to confirm it at https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/logging#basic_logging And I couldn't understand about the console. Can I ask you about the console you say?

Comment: I was just referring to develop tools in google chrome

Comment: Thank you for replying. I could understand about the console you think.