# Combining results of paginated calls with CoinMarketCap API v2

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script, pagination

The new CoinMarketCap api (v2) has a 100 result limit on the following call...

```
https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/
```

Which you can paginate through using...

```
https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/?start=101
```

I was previously loading all coins with code like this...

```
  var cmcUrl = 'https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/';
  var cmcResponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch(cmcUrl);
  var cmcData = JSON.parse(cmcResponse.getContentText());
```

But now I need to make multiple calls which I was hoping to do with something basic like this...

```
var cmcUrl = 'https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/';
var cmcResponse = "";
for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    cmcResponse = cmcResponse + UrlFetchApp.fetch(cmcUrl + "?start=" + (i * 100 + 1));
}
var cmcData = JSON.parse(cmcResponse.getContentText());
```

But a simple addition of the previous cmcResponse to another isn't working when I come to use JSON.parse and I'm hoping there's a another way to sum the responses of each request so they retain the same object format.

I did find a hint using fetchAll in this post, but would prefer to simply sum responses if it's possible...

[Using coinmarketcap api v2 with google sheets - adding to js object with multiple calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50595612/using-coinmarketcap-api-v2-with-google-sheets-adding-to-js-object-with-multipl?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: `parse` each response individually, then combine them as desired?

Comment: @certainperformance - by simply using the "+" operator?

Comment: No, `JSON.parse` each response individually, put it in an array, and transform the array as needed after

Comment: @CertainPerformance - ok, so you mean store each of the parsed responses in an array and transform outside of the loop.  My question is really how to transform outside of the loop - I can't just loop through the array later and sum each row together?

Comment: No, you cannot just concatenate JSON strings like that. Transforming objects is far easier than transforming strings.

Comment: @certainperformance - I'm sorry but I don't understand what you're suggesting

Comment: He's saying treat each response as you would if it were the only response - i.e. parse it from string into its object structure, which is probably an `Array` of key-value objects, and then use standard object methods such as `Array#concat` to combine them. Simply joining two different string representations of a complex structure is not the same as extending the object structure of one to include the data from both. You might need to step back and do more language learning.

Comment: You want to sum each response retrieved by ``UrlFetchApp.fetch()``. Is my understanding correct?